# How to change remote directory location to a path out of SFTP root in WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am SQL DBA using WinSCP command line in SSIS package to download backup file from SFTP server.

My default remote directory on the server is `C:\sftp_root`, which I can see in WinSCP as `/`. But my backup files is at `D:\Backup` folder. I can't keep my backup file on C drive as it's having space issue.

I am using below command line using `WinSCP.com` in my SSIS package to download the backup file. When trying to change my remote directory, I am getting an error *"No Such file exists"*.

> /log=D:\DBA\winscp.log /console /command "option batch abort" "option
>   confirm off" "open sftp://sftp_dba:Password@2.2.2.0:22
>   -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2000 2s:2g:44:12:56:ws:ss:as""" "cd /D:\Backup" "get *.bak D:\Backups\" "rm *.bak" "exit"

First of all I am wondering if it is possible to change remote directory path in the above command line? If yes, please help me with the syntax.

I am stuck here and need experts help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what the `cd` command in your command-line does, right? And actually you can specify the source remote path in the `get` command itself. So I'm not sure, what your problem is.

Comment: Above command giving me error 'No Such file exists' I have given permission on Drive and Folder but still getting an error.

Comment: When you login in WinSCP GUI, can you navigate to `/D:\Backup`? Show us a screenshot.

Comment: Log File

https://www.screencast.com/t/L6kM7siZn8m

Comment: No. I can't navigate to D:\Backup. It taking me to default remote location which is C:\sftp_root.

Comment: Your comment is bit confusing. The fact that the default location is `C:\sftp_root` does not mean that you cannot navigate to  `D:\Backup`. What did you try to navigate there. Also is the default path as you see it in WinSCP really `C:\sftp_root`? Or with forward slash?

Comment: In WinSCP, I am getting default path as '/ <roor>' but it's navigate to C:\sftp_root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What path(s) on the server file system you can access with SFTP protocol is a matter of configuration of the SFTP server.

If the SFTP server is configured to map only `C:\sftp_root` to SFTP root path `/` (aka to jail your account to `C:\sftp_root`), there's no magical way for you to circumvent that (escape the jail).

You have to reconfigure the SFTP server to allow an access to a different path.

E.g. you can map the `D:\Backup` to `/backup`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to escape from jail? Is this change in WinSCP application?

Comment: As my answer sais, it's a matter of configuration of the SFTP server. It has nothing to do with a client (WinSCP).